# Is there a nilpotent and idempotent pair such that their product is the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence, idempotents

Trying to gain a better understanding of linear algebra. Is there such a nilpotent matrix ($A^2=0$) and idempotent matrix ($B^2=B$) such that their product is equal to the identity? $$AB=I$$ and/or $$BA=I$$ Similarly, can nilpotents and idempotents be each other's inverses? If not matrices, are there any other mathematical objects that may have one or all of these properties?

Comment: What do you know about the ranks of matrices and their products?

Comment: Consider the determinants.

Answer (score 1):

If $AB = I$ and $A^2 = 0,$ then multiplying $A$ on the left of $AB = I$ would give $$0 = 0B = AAB = AI = A$$
and then 
$$I = AB = 0B = 0$$
so this would require the identity object to equal the zero object.

Comment: Note that the only properties used that aren't by definition are $0B = 0$ and associativity.  In most examples where we have a zero element, though, $0B = 0$ holds, so the only times this could reasonably be expected to hold is when multiplication isn't associative.